# Xubuntu 18.0.4 LTS: suddenly cannot connect to home wifi

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, internet, 18.04

I upgraded my laptop to 18.0.4 last week. Everything was okay mostly. I was never able to connect to work Wi-Fi, but I could connect fine at home … then randomly I couldn't anymore. I didn't install any software or modify any settings. I was just reading a page on MakeUseOf.com, than suddenly I couldn't connect anymore. I can see the network in the WiFi widget, but when I try to connect, nothing happens. Please help me.